# Printing syntax colored source code with vim bash script without flickering

Tags: bash, pdf, vim, printing

I wrote this script to help print source files to PDF via Vim, which I named `vimpdf`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Printing $1 to pdf";
vim -e -c "hardcopy > %.ps" -c q $1;
ps2pdf $1.ps;
```

The script works nicely, the PDF is generated with syntax highlight, but unfortunately it causes some flickering in the terminal, for example, after running a command line like this,

```
$ vimpdf file.py
```

I tried to pass to vim the `-s` option, which removes the flickering, but causes the PDF to loose the syntax coloring.

How can I remove the flickering and still get syntax coloring?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect vim's output:

`vim -e -c "hardcopy > %.ps" -c q $1 >/dev/null;`

(BTW, you don't have to terminate lines in BASH scripts with semicolons.)

Comment: Thanks! That made my script really useful.